# object test is not a member of package org.elasticsearch

Tags: java, scala, sbt, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to use class `ESTestCase` from the package `org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase`
I am following this link -> 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/using-elasticsearch-test-classes.html
I am using sbt project here are the library dependencies is the build.sbt file

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "5.6.0",
"org.elasticsearch.client" % "transport" % "5.6.0",
                "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-expressions" % "6.6.0",
                "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.9.0",
                "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-test-framework" % "6.6.0" % "test",
                "org.elasticsearch.test" % "framework" % "5.6.0" % "test",
```

when i try to import these two lines

```
import org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase
import org.elasticsearch.transport.MockTransportClient
```

eclipse is not showing any compile time error but got following errors on `sbt-compile`

[

```
error] /myproject/app/CampaignController.scala:44: object test is not a member of package org.elasticsearch
[error] import org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase
[error]                          ^
[error] /myproject/app/CampaignController.scala:45: object MockTransportClient is not a member of package org.elasticsearch.transport
[error] import org.elasticsearch.transport.MockTransportClient
[error]        ^
```

I am using ElasticSearch 5.6.0 ,please helP what is causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `% "test"` in dependencies.
If dependency ends with `% "test"`, it will compile only for your tests.

So normally it is assumed that you will use  `org.elasticsearch.test.ESTestCase` and other testing stuff in your test module (src/test/scala or something like that).

Probably you are importing elastic search test dependencies into the application(src/main...) and that's why you are getting the error.

If you import them in tests module (src/test/scala), it will work.

But if you really need to import it into your application code, then just
remove  `% "test"` from dependencies.

```
...
"org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-test-framework" % "6.6.0",
"org.elasticsearch.test" % "framework" % "5.6.0"
...
```

Here is a sbt doc which explains it:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html (search for "Per-configuration dependencies")